# Call to get OCI announcements API via secrets.vaults.uk-london-1.oci.oraclecloud.com domain returns NotAuthenticated error

Tags: node.js, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Even though on postman, OCI_REST_INITIALIZATION/ONE_TIME_INITIALIZATION_CALL and OCI_REST_COLLECTION/GET_OCI_ANNOUNCEMENTS collections are working fine. But when calling from Nodejs project/program, below error response is returned.

```
{
  "code" : "NotAuthenticated",
  "message" : "The required information to complete authentication was not provided or was incorrect."
}
```

Below is my Nodejs code

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const fs = require('fs');
const request = require('request');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

const vaultUrl = process.env.vaultUrl;
const secretBundleUrl = `${vaultUrl}/${process.env.secretBundle}/${process.env.vaultSecret}`;

const tenancyId = process.env.tenancyId;
const authUserId = process.env.authUserId;
const keyFingerprint = process.env.keyFingerprint;

const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('./oci_private_key.pem', 'utf8');

const header = {
  alg: 'RS256',
  typ: 'JWT',
  kid: keyFingerprint,
};

const payload = {
  iss: tenancyId,
  sub: authUserId,
  aud: `${vaultUrl}/${process.env.secretBundle}`,
  iat: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
  exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600,
};

const jwtToken = jwt.sign(payload, privateKey, { header });

const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: secretBundleUrl,
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${jwtToken}`,
  },
};

request(options, function (error, response) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log(response.body);
});
```

Code output

```
{
  "code" : "NotAuthenticated",
  "message" : "The required information to complete authentication was not provided or was incorrect."
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

can you try using oci-sdk for typescript and JavaScript and see if that works for you?  https://www.npmjs.com/package/oci-sdk

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).